# Inherit BackgroundService and Dispose()

Tags: c#, azure, idisposable

I'm looking at `BackgroundService` from [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

The class that I'm converting to inherit from `BackgroundService` implemented `IDisposable`.

Since `Dispose(bool disposing)` is not exposed by `BackgroundService` I cannot call `base.Dispose(disposing);` in my service's `Dispose(bool disposing)`.

Is the idea that classes that inherit from `BackgroundService` cleanup in `StopAsync` (or have the cleanup code in `ExecuteAsync`)?

Comment: It says this for `StopAsync`: "Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.". I guess you would do clean-up there.

Comment: You could also implement `IHostedService` directly?

Answer (score 7):

`BackgroundService` contains this code in `StopAsync`

```
/// <summary>
/// Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">Indicates that the shutdown process should no longer be graceful.</param>
public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  if (this._executingTask == null)
    return;
  try
  {
    this._stoppingCts.Cancel();
  }
  finally
  {
    Task task = await Task.WhenAny(this._executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));
  }
}
```

Thus this is the way to do cleanup when you inherit from `BackgroundService`

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    // here you register to be notified when stoppingToken is Canceled in BackgroundService
    stoppingToken.Register(ShutDown);

    // start some work

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void ShutDown()
{
    // Cleanup here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The `IHostedService` background task execution is coordinated with the lifetime of the application (host or microservice, for that matter). 
>   You register tasks when the application starts and you have the opportunity to do some graceful action or clean-up when the application is shutting down.

The `ExecuteAsync` register tasks when the application start. By default, the cancellation token is set with 5 second timeout. 
This means our service is expected to cancel within 5 seconds otherwise it will be more abruptly killed.

> Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.

When you `ExecuteAsync` shutdown it will trigger the `StopAsync` task.

And the you could run your graceful clean up actions in StopAsync . If you do not override the StopAsync in the class that inherit from BackgroundService, it will execute the StopAsync method in BackgroundService.